# Dialog with more than 2 buttons

Tags: android, button, dialog

I have a dialog with: Title, Message and 2 Buttons (Neutral and Negative) i tried to put another Neutral or Negavite button but it shows only one button of each(Neutral and Negative), so is there a way to put a button or do I have to create a custom layout of the dialog? If so, how to do it?

code:

```
      AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);      
    dialogo.setMessage(msg);
    dialogo.setTitle(titulo);
    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    dialogo.setNegativeButton("Delete", deletar);
    dialogo.show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a third button using `setPositiveButton` but aside from that, you'll have to set a custom view.  To set a custom view you just call `setView(yourView)` with the `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Answer (score 4):

You can have upto three buttons by default, namely Neutral, Negative and Positive. Beyond that, you will either need to use a custom layout in the dialog, or create your own dialog.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple ...

```
void multiPopup() {
    AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    ad.setTitle("Choose one...");
    ad.setItems(
      new String[] {"red", "green", "blue", "cancel"},
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i("dev", "clicked .. " + which);
        }
    });
    ad.create().show();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default Android's Dialog with a list of clickable options.

```
    String[] dialogOptions = new String[]{ "Option 0", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("DIALOG TITLE")
           .setItems(dialogOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      switch (which){
                           case 0:
                                //Option #0 picked, do something
                                break;
                           case 1:
                                //Option #1 picked, do something
                                break;
                           case 2:
                                //Option #2 picked, do something
                                break;
                           case 3:
                                //Option #3 picked, do something
                                break;
                      }
                 }
           })
           .create()
           .show();
```

**Note:** During my tests, setMessage() and list was not working together, so I recommend you only use setTitle() and skip setMessage().
Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#AddingAList